# Query with multiples conditions in CASE WHEN

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-like, case-when

I'm trying to manage to find a best way to develop a "simple" query which has some conditions.

Basically this is the sample of the query I'm trying to run, it works like this, but I was wondering if there is a "cleaner" way to do it, because I have several `case when` conditions in my full query

```
select
    case 
       when col_1 like '%OHUB%7E%' or col_1 like '%8E%' or col_1 like '%9E%' or col_1 not like '%10E%' 
            and col_2 like '%OHUB%1E%' or col_2 like '%OHUB%2E%' or col_2 like '%OHUB%3E%' 
            and col_3 like '%OHUB%11E%' or col_3 like '%OHUB%10E%'
          then col_1 = 'OBJECT' 
    end col_1
from table_x
```

I was wondering if I can group all of the conditions of each column to not repeat the column over and over.

something like this :

```
select
case when col_1 Like ('%OHUB%7E%' or '%8E%' or '%9E%' or not Like '%10E%') 
        and col_2  Like ('%OHUB%1E%' or '%OHUB%2E%' or '%OHUB%3E%')
        and col_3  Like ('%OHUB%11E%' or'%OHUB%10E%')
    then col_1 = 'OBJECT' 
    end col_1
from table_x
```

I tried but, couldn't find another way that work

Comment: Mixing the use of AND and OR without parentheses is often faulty logic. Make sure you test this using very well designed testing data to validate your logic.

Answer (score 2):

If there are a lot of values, you can record them in a #temporary/@table variable/cte and perform some check like the below:

```
DECLARE @Col_1_Values TABLE
(
    [value] NVARCHAR(128)
);


INSERT INTO @Col_1_Values ([value])
VALUES ('%OHUB%7E%')
      ,('%8E%')
      ,('%9E%')

DECLARE @test_string NVARCHAR(12) = 'xxx9Exxx';

SELECT IIF(EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM @Col_1_Values WHERE @test_string LIKE [value]), 1, 0);
```

Then in the future you can simple add new values, without changing the code.

Comment: @gfernandes if this answer worked for you then you should really click the little tick to mark it, otherwise your question keeps showing up as an open question to other SO users.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine your conditions.  So something like this:

```
select (case when col_1 like '%[789]E%' and
                  col_2 like '%OHUB%[123]E%' and
                  col_3 like '%OHUB%1[10]E%' 
             then col_1 = 'OBJECT' 
        end) col_1
from table_x
```

(I don't understand the `or col_1 not like '%10E%'` condition so I removed it.)

SQL Server doesn't (directly) support regular expressions.  However, it has extended `LIKE` patterns so they are useful for what you want to do.